# What does the question mark mean in public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)?

Tags: swift, uiview, nscoder

I don't think the question mark in `public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is about optionals. Also, when I override it I find I don't need to write the question mark at all.

So what does it mean exactly ?

--- Update ---

The comment below helped me figure that out. It is called a "failable initializer". Another example that can make the concept easier to understand is UIFont's convenience init because the UIFont may not exist.

```
public /*not inherited*/ init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat)
```

Comment: I just downloaded the latest 2.2 version and found it called "failable initializer". The 2.1 version didn't mean it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not just for `public init()` but for any `init()`

Answer (score 10):

It's called failable initializer. In the book, The Swift Programming Language, it describes it as

> “It is sometimes useful to define a class, structure, or enumeration for which initialization can fail. This failure might be triggered by invalid initialization parameter values, the absence of a required external resource, or some other condition that prevents initialization from succeeding.”

Check the "Failable Initializers" section in the [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

Comment: Yes I have figured that out (Swift 2.1 book didn't mention it, see my comments above). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**`init?()` or Failable Initializers**

`init?()` or `Failable Initializers` means that the initialiser **can** return `nil`. It means that object couldn't be constructed(creation fails) and it is useful to pass **any** parameter into `init` which is responsible to create an object or just fail because of some reason.